# I have problems with sqlite3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sqlite

I'm pretty new to programming and i have never made any big project. Currently I'm learning c++ language and I want to learn sqlite3 to store data in this database.

My problem:

I don't know how to `#include "sqlite3.h"`. I have downloaded source code from sqlite website and added files into my visual studio 2012 project and then tried to include, but it didn't work:

> Error: "cannot open include file 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory...

So yeah.. its totally noob question^^ I cant make sqlite3 to work in my visual studio project if you know what I mean.

Comment: Did you copy the files into the same folder as your project? I would open an explorer window on your project and search for sqlite3.h.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you update your project settings to include the path to the files you downloaded.  simply go to the project settings, C/C++ general properties and look on the right for "Additional Include Directories".  You probably need to update the path to the lib files as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i dont have lib files... I only have header files.